# Gerando uma string hexadecimal

Tags: java, hexadecimal

Boa tarde pessoal, bem estou gerando uma string hexadecimal aleatória nesse padrão: 81c1328d-4dae-4af7-9974-893bb8ec90d4

Porém gostaria de otimizar esse código aqui:

```
public String geraKee(){

    String letras = "abcdef0123456789";  

    Random random = new Random();  

    String armazenaChaves = "";  
    int index = -1;  

    for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {  
       index = random.nextInt( letras.length() );  
       armazenaChaves += letras.substring( index, index + 1 );  
    }
    armazenaChaves += "-";
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {  
       index = random.nextInt( letras.length() );  
       armazenaChaves += letras.substring( index, index + 1 );  
    }
    armazenaChaves += "-4";
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {  
       index = random.nextInt( letras.length() );  
       armazenaChaves += letras.substring( index, index + 1 );  
    }
    armazenaChaves += "-";
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {  
       index = random.nextInt( letras.length() );  
       armazenaChaves += letras.substring( index, index + 1 );  
    }
    armazenaChaves += "-";
    for( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) {  
       index = random.nextInt( letras.length() );  
       armazenaChaves += letras.substring( index, index + 1 );  
    }
    return armazenaChaves;  

}
```

Comment: Qual o problema com o código?

Comment: Nenhum só acho ele desnecessariamente grande.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não seria o caso de usar um `UUID.randomUUID()` simplesmente?

Exemplo:

```
import java.util.UUID;

class GerarUUID {
   public static void main(String[] aArgs) {
      UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
      System.out.println("UUID " + id);
   }
}
```

Saída (a cada chamada sai um valor diferente, pois é aleatório):

```
UUID 7d7b34ea-7faf-4935-9829-995975751494
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/v9GFb9)**.

Comment: Obrigado cara, não conhecia essa função ainda, mas é exatamente o que eu precisava.